# Wish to Know Better Strategy for Fetching Multiple URLS Javascript + Python

Tags: javascript, python

I have bunch of urls to fetch. I wish to know which one would be better strategy for speed and good User experience.

Strategy:

1. Using Javascript (fetch or XHR). All urls will be fetched on client side.
2. Send only one fetch/XHR (calling python in JS) to python and get all the URL's data in python and send back the response to client.

Please let me know which one would be better strategy.

Thank you,
Namratha Patil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network requests are computationally expensive, so batching and sending only one request is almost always preferable.

Comment: Thank you Ivan. I am taking your solution as only one request.

Answer (score 1):

You can `priorities` your data loading on may factors like:

> Whether the data is required in first fold to render elements and similar factors. if you go with 2nd strategy if will delay the loading and you will have bad user experience.